# Compile error when I mix Implicits, type parameters and Nothing

Tags: scala, implicit

Why does this not compile with type parameters:

> error: value explode is not a member of Test.A[Nothing]

If I remove them, then it compiles. What am I not understanding, and more importantly, what can I do to fix it.

```
object Test extends App {

  implicit class B[E](set: A[E]) {
    def explode() = println("boom")
  }

  case class A[E](name: String)

  A[Nothing]("coldplay").explode()
}
```

(The type parameters in this example don't do anything, but in the real world use case I have multiple type parameters, and some can be Nothing and some are not).

Comment: Apparently, setting the type parameter to `Nothing` directly is what is causing the issue: both bare `A("coldplay").explode()` (which is, in fact, `A[Nothing]`) and any other specified type, for example, `A[String]("coldplay").explode()` work just fine. As to 'why', I'll wait for someone else to answer, simply because I don't know... :)

Comment: Yeah I use Nothing in the real world use case and that's when it started blowing up.

Comment: If you use `-Xlog-implicit-conversions` and `-Xlog-implicits` you can get more info. It looks like `A("coldplay").explode()` works because the implicit conversion is applied before resolving the type parameters. With `A[Nothing]("coldplay").explode()`, the compiler refuses to infer `Nothing` as the type parameter to `B`, though I have no idea why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really doesn't like to infer Nothing:

```
scala> implicit def a2b(a: A[Nothing]): B[Nothing] = new B(a)
<console>:17: error: type mismatch;
 found   : A[Nothing]
 required: A[T]
Note: Nothing <: T, but class A is invariant in type E.
You may wish to define E as +E instead. (SLS 4.5)
       implicit def a2b(a: A[Nothing]): B[Nothing] = new B(a)
                                                           ^

scala> implicit def a2b(a: A[Nothing]): B[Nothing] = new B[Nothing](a)
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
a2b: (a: A[Nothing])B[Nothing]

scala> A[Nothing]("coldplay").explode()
boom
```

The `-Ytyper-debug`:

```
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    solving for (T: ?T)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- $iw.this.X.B BYVALmode-EXPRmode-FUNmode-POLYmode (silent solving: type T: method f in X) implicits disabled
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    [adapt] [T](set: $line3.$read.$iw.$iw.X.A[T])$line3.$read.$iw.$iw... adapted to [T](set: $line3.$read.$iw.$iw.X.A[T])$line3.$read.$iw.$iw...
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    \-> (set: X.A[T])X.B[T]
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    solving for (T: ?T, T: ?T)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    \-> <error>
<console>:10: error: value explode is not a member of X.A[Nothing]
       def f() = A[Nothing]("coldplay").explode() }
```

Comment: Works for me. Just don't get rid of the parameterized implicit conversion — have both in scope. Try it out. Also, the first attempt in this answer shows another solution: `class A[+E](...)`

Comment: My class was already co-variant in the real code, didn't seem to help.

Comment: @monkjack This is besides the implicit class.

Comment: Yeah the covariance doesn't matter, as my class was covariant all along anyway.

Comment: Odd. Using your example code from your question and adding the covariance, it compiles. I wonder what makes it not matter in your full code?

Comment: Either A or B covariant.